# Trying to check coordinates if they exist in the list so I could ignore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I with a team trying to make Tetris Attack/Panel de Pon. I did debug and saw that  `Debug.Log("Match?");` is not executable. Before `foreach (Vector2Int n in exist)` Debug working.

How could I change my script?

With this part of code, I am trying to get cells that match with each other horizontally and vertically.

```
private List<Vector2Int> FindCellNeighbor(int x, int y, List<Vector2Int> matching)
    {
        matching.Add(new Vector2Int(x, y));
        List<Vector2Int> exist = new List<Vector2Int>();
        foreach (Vector2Int n in exist)
        {
            if (!n.Equals(matching))
            {
                Debug.Log("Match?");
                if (x >= 0 && x <= height && y >= 0 && y <= width)      // checks if cell coordiantes hits the borders
                {
                    if (data[x, y] == data[x + 1, y])
                    {
                        matching.AddRange(FindCellNeighbor(x + 1, y, matching));
                        exist = matching;
                        Debug.Log("x + 1");
                    }
                    if (data[x, y] == data[x - 1, y])
                    {
                        matching.AddRange(FindCellNeighbor(x - 1, y, matching));
                        exist = matching;
                        Debug.Log("x - 1");
                    }
                    if (data[x, y] == data[x, y + 1])
                    {
                        matching.AddRange(FindCellNeighbor(x, y + 1, matching));
                        exist = matching;
                        Debug.Log("y + 1");
                    }
                    if (data[x, y] == data[x, y - 1])
                    {
                        matching.AddRange(FindCellNeighbor(x, y - 1, matching));
                        exist = matching;
                        Debug.Log("y - 1");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return matching;
    }
```

Full codes [GitHub](https://github.com/dasna111/slide-pop)

Comment: Just a doubt: is it correct "x <= height" and "y <= width"? Logically, I would exchange those. But it all depends on your coordinate system, of course.

Comment: @Andrea It is correct. (It gave overflow before I tried to check if there are duplicates in the list). It makes easier for me to write like this.

Comment: Note that [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) is a JavaScript derivative made for Unity. UnityScript != C#. This is clearly C# code.

Comment: What is it you expect `!n.Equals(matching)` to do?

Comment: @JohnWu I should check if in exist list already exists any value from matching list.